# 'static' object in a function

Tags: c, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does gcc automatically initialize static variables to zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294772/does-gcc-automatically-initialize-static-variables-to-zero)

Are statically declared objects inside a function guaranteed to be initialized with `0`?

For example:

```
int func(void)
{
   static int x;
   ...
}
```

Does the standard promise that `x = 0` upon the first invocation of `func()`?

Answer (score 5):

The [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says:

> 5.1.2  Execution environments
>
> ...   All  objects  in  static  storage  shall   be
>          initialized  (set  to  their  initial values) before program
>          startup.

And it also says that a local variable defined with `static` qualifier has "static storage" and that in the absence of an initialization all objects take the value 0 of the right type for them.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes.

Static, uninitialised variables reside in the `.bss` segment of the executable and the operating system allocates and zeroes them on program startup, before `main` is invoked.

Comment: It is still a good idea to initialize it.

Comment: It is a good practice, IMHO.  This way you never have to think about which variables are initialized automatically and which are not.  Let's say you later decide that `x` should not be static, but forget to initialize it, and that bug will be a royal pain to find.

Comment: It is **not** "a good idea" to initialize it explicitly. For various reasons, almost all compilers will put explicitly-initialized variables in `.data` rather than `.bss` (or equivalents), enlarging your binary for **no purpose**. This can make a big difference with large arrays or structures.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. For more insight you can refer to exact same question asked a while ago here:

[Does gcc automatically initialize static variables to zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294772/does-gcc-automatically-initialize-static-variables-to-zero)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does get initialized to zero. But, however, it might be still not a great idea to use static method variables at all. C# has explicitly avoided the confusion, and have dropped support for static method variables.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/05/11/why-doesn-t-c-support-static-method-variables.aspx

Answer (score 0):

All static variables are stored in Datasection in the memory section, where all the variables are set to default values.