# Transferring values to variables after initial case

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
int s= int(sr/nt);
int temp1 = 0; //initialization for the first time case

// the following is the logic for the subsequent cases
int temp2= temp1; // a non-zero value of 's', calculated previously and stored in temp1 is now transferred to temp2
temp1 = s; // currently calculated value of 's' stored in temp1

double moving_average = (temp1+temp2)/2; // not relevant to the problem
```

My problem is that I require the above code to run a number of times when it is called; and need the previous values of 's' stored in temp1 to transfer it to temp2 in order to calculate moving average.

As I initialize temp1 to zero in the code, it will be executed for the subsequent iterations and I won't get what I need.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You should make it `static`

```
static int temp1 = 0;
```

This will ensure that it is only initialized once and thereafter won't be reinitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

- Move `temp1` and its initialization out of the code and pass `temp1` to the function ( I am assuming the above code is in a function). The calling code would manage `temp1` and ensure it is the same variable passed to the function:

  ```
  void moving_average_func(int& a_temp1)
  {
  }

  int temp1 = 0;
  moving_average_func(temp1);
  moving_average_func(temp1);
  ```
- Make `temp1` a `static` variable so the initialization occurs once only:

  ```
  static int temp1 = 0;
  ```

It is simpler to restart the calculation with the non-`static` solution and avoids synchronization requirements if multiple threads are using the same code block (as the multiple threads would be accessing the same `temp1` in the `static` solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can make `temp1` a static variable, such that it retains its value between function calls. This way it will only be be initialized to zero the first time the function is called - note it is automatically initialized to zero (as per the [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294772/does-gcc-automatically-initialize-static-variables-to-zero)), so you don't have to do it explicitly yourself. Example of how it works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void asd()
{
    static int a=1;
    cout << a << endl;
    a++;
}

int main()
{
    asd(); //outputs 1
    asd(); //outputs 2
    return 0;
}
```