# Why is this Program always giving the same output: 0x63

Tags: c

I have the following codes. An output is generated after compiling, however, it is always producing the output 0x63. I am not sure if the program (from CHStone benchmark) is wrong or that I did not write the computations in the main() correctly. Or, is the output correct? The output remains the same: 0x63 even with different switch..case. I am really confused. Can someone please give me some help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SIZE_A 16
#define SIZE_B 16
int nb;
int statemt[32];

static int Sbox[16][16] = {
{0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b,
0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76},
{0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf,
0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0},
{0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1,
0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15},
{0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2,
0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75},
{0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3,
0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84},
{0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39,
0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf},
{0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f,
0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8},
{0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21,
0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2},
{0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d,
0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73},
{0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14,
0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb},
{0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62,
0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79},
{0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea,
0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08},
{0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f,
0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a},
{0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9,
0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e},
{0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9,
0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf},
{0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f,
0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16}
};

static int invSbox[16][16] = {
{0x52, 0x09, 0x6a, 0xd5, 0x30, 0x36, 0xa5, 0x38, 0xbf, 0x40, 0xa3, 0x9e,
0x81, 0xf3, 0xd7, 0xfb},
{0x7c, 0xe3, 0x39, 0x82, 0x9b, 0x2f, 0xff, 0x87, 0x34, 0x8e, 0x43, 0x44,
0xc4, 0xde, 0xe9, 0xcb},
{0x54, 0x7b, 0x94, 0x32, 0xa6, 0xc2, 0x23, 0x3d, 0xee, 0x4c, 0x95, 0x0b,
0x42, 0xfa, 0xc3, 0x4e},
{0x08, 0x2e, 0xa1, 0x66, 0x28, 0xd9, 0x24, 0xb2, 0x76, 0x5b, 0xa2, 0x49,
0x6d, 0x8b, 0xd1, 0x25},
{0x72, 0xf8, 0xf6, 0x64, 0x86, 0x68, 0x98, 0x16, 0xd4, 0xa4, 0x5c, 0xcc,
0x5d, 0x65, 0xb6, 0x92},
{0x6c, 0x70, 0x48, 0x50, 0xfd, 0xed, 0xb9, 0xda, 0x5e, 0x15, 0x46, 0x57,
0xa7, 0x8d, 0x9d, 0x84},
{0x90, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x00, 0x8c, 0xbc, 0xd3, 0x0a, 0xf7, 0xe4, 0x58, 0x05,
0xb8, 0xb3, 0x45, 0x06},
{0xd0, 0x2c, 0x1e, 0x8f, 0xca, 0x3f, 0x0f, 0x02, 0xc1, 0xaf, 0xbd, 0x03,
0x01, 0x13, 0x8a, 0x6b},
{0x3a, 0x91, 0x11, 0x41, 0x4f, 0x67, 0xdc, 0xea, 0x97, 0xf2, 0xcf, 0xce,
0xf0, 0xb4, 0xe6, 0x73},
{0x96, 0xac, 0x74, 0x22, 0xe7, 0xad, 0x35, 0x85, 0xe2, 0xf9, 0x37, 0xe8,
0x1c, 0x75, 0xdf, 0x6e},
{0x47, 0xf1, 0x1a, 0x71, 0x1d, 0x29, 0xc5, 0x89, 0x6f, 0xb7, 0x62, 0x0e,
0xaa, 0x18, 0xbe, 0x1b},
{0xfc, 0x56, 0x3e, 0x4b, 0xc6, 0xd2, 0x79, 0x20, 0x9a, 0xdb, 0xc0, 0xfe,
0x78, 0xcd, 0x5a, 0xf4},
{0x1f, 0xdd, 0xa8, 0x33, 0x88, 0x07, 0xc7, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x59,
0x27, 0x80, 0xec, 0x5f},
{0x60, 0x51, 0x7f, 0xa9, 0x19, 0xb5, 0x4a, 0x0d, 0x2d, 0xe5, 0x7a, 0x9f,
0x93, 0xc9, 0x9c, 0xef},
{0xa0, 0xe0, 0x3b, 0x4d, 0xae, 0x2a, 0xf5, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0xeb, 0xbb, 0x3c,
0x83, 0x53, 0x99, 0x61},
{0x17, 0x2b, 0x04, 0x7e, 0xba, 0x77, 0xd6, 0x26, 0xe1, 0x69, 0x14, 0x63,
0x55, 0x21, 0x0c, 0x7d}
};

/* ********* ByteSub & ShiftRow ********* */
void ByteSub_ShiftRow (int statemt[32], int nb)
{
int temp;
nb=4;
switch (nb)
{
case 4:
  temp = Sbox[statemt[1] >> 4][statemt[1] & 0xf];
  statemt[1] = Sbox[statemt[5] >> 4][statemt[5] & 0xf];
  statemt[5] = Sbox[statemt[9] >> 4][statemt[9] & 0xf];
  statemt[9] = Sbox[statemt[13] >> 4][statemt[13] & 0xf];
  statemt[13] = temp;

  temp = Sbox[statemt[2] >> 4][statemt[2] & 0xf];
  statemt[2] = Sbox[statemt[10] >> 4][statemt[10] & 0xf];
  statemt[10] = temp;
  temp = Sbox[statemt[6] >> 4][statemt[6] & 0xf];
  statemt[6] = Sbox[statemt[14] >> 4][statemt[14] & 0xf];
  statemt[14] = temp;

  temp = Sbox[statemt[3] >> 4][statemt[3] & 0xf];
  statemt[3] = Sbox[statemt[15] >> 4][statemt[15] & 0xf];
  statemt[15] = Sbox[statemt[11] >> 4][statemt[11] & 0xf];
  statemt[11] = Sbox[statemt[7] >> 4][statemt[7] & 0xf];
  statemt[7] = temp;

  statemt[0] = Sbox[statemt[0] >> 4][statemt[0] & 0xf];
  statemt[4] = Sbox[statemt[4] >> 4][statemt[4] & 0xf];
  statemt[8] = Sbox[statemt[8] >> 4][statemt[8] & 0xf];
  statemt[12] = Sbox[statemt[12] >> 4][statemt[12] & 0xf];

  printf("temp is = 0x%02X\n",temp);
  printf("statemt[1] is = 0x%02X\n",statemt[1]);
  printf("statemt[2] is = 0x%02X\n",statemt[2]);
  printf("statemt[3] is = 0x%02X\n",statemt[3]);
  printf("statemt[4] is = 0x%02X\n",statemt[4]);
  printf("statemt[5] is = 0x%02X\n",statemt[5]);
  printf("statemt[6] is = 0x%02X\n",statemt[6]);
  break;
case 6:
  temp = Sbox[statemt[1] >> 4][statemt[1] & 0xf];
  statemt[1] = Sbox[statemt[5] >> 4][statemt[5] & 0xf];
  statemt[5] = Sbox[statemt[9] >> 4][statemt[9] & 0xf];
  statemt[9] = Sbox[statemt[13] >> 4][statemt[13] & 0xf];
  statemt[13] = Sbox[statemt[17] >> 4][statemt[17] & 0xf];
  statemt[17] = Sbox[statemt[21] >> 4][statemt[21] & 0xf];
  statemt[21] = temp;

  temp = Sbox[statemt[2] >> 4][statemt[2] & 0xf];
  statemt[2] = Sbox[statemt[10] >> 4][statemt[10] & 0xf];
  statemt[10] = Sbox[statemt[18] >> 4][statemt[18] & 0xf];
  statemt[18] = temp;
  temp = Sbox[statemt[6] >> 4][statemt[6] & 0xf];
  statemt[6] = Sbox[statemt[14] >> 4][statemt[14] & 0xf];
  statemt[14] = Sbox[statemt[22] >> 4][statemt[22] & 0xf];
  statemt[22] = temp;

  temp = Sbox[statemt[3] >> 4][statemt[3] & 0xf];
  statemt[3] = Sbox[statemt[15] >> 4][statemt[15] & 0xf];
  statemt[15] = temp;
  temp = Sbox[statemt[7] >> 4][statemt[7] & 0xf];
  statemt[7] = Sbox[statemt[19] >> 4][statemt[19] & 0xf];
  statemt[19] = temp;
  temp = Sbox[statemt[11] >> 4][statemt[11] & 0xf];
  statemt[11] = Sbox[statemt[23] >> 4][statemt[23] & 0xf];
  statemt[23] = temp;

  statemt[0] = Sbox[statemt[0] >> 4][statemt[0] & 0xf];
  statemt[4] = Sbox[statemt[4] >> 4][statemt[4] & 0xf];
  statemt[8] = Sbox[statemt[8] >> 4][statemt[8] & 0xf];
  statemt[12] = Sbox[statemt[12] >> 4][statemt[12] & 0xf];
  statemt[16] = Sbox[statemt[16] >> 4][statemt[16] & 0xf];
  statemt[20] = Sbox[statemt[20] >> 4][statemt[20] & 0xf];
  break;
case 8:
  temp = Sbox[statemt[1] >> 4][statemt[1] & 0xf];
  statemt[1] = Sbox[statemt[5] >> 4][statemt[5] & 0xf];
  statemt[5] = Sbox[statemt[9] >> 4][statemt[9] & 0xf];
  statemt[9] = Sbox[statemt[13] >> 4][statemt[13] & 0xf];
  statemt[13] = Sbox[statemt[17] >> 4][statemt[17] & 0xf];
  statemt[17] = Sbox[statemt[21] >> 4][statemt[21] & 0xf];
  statemt[21] = Sbox[statemt[25] >> 4][statemt[25] & 0xf];
  statemt[25] = Sbox[statemt[29] >> 4][statemt[29] & 0xf];
  statemt[29] = temp;

  temp = Sbox[statemt[2] >> 4][statemt[2] & 0xf];
  statemt[2] = Sbox[statemt[14] >> 4][statemt[14] & 0xf];
  statemt[14] = Sbox[statemt[26] >> 4][statemt[26] & 0xf];
  statemt[26] = Sbox[statemt[6] >> 4][statemt[6] & 0xf];
  statemt[6] = Sbox[statemt[18] >> 4][statemt[18] & 0xf];
  statemt[18] = Sbox[statemt[30] >> 4][statemt[30] & 0xf];
  statemt[30] = Sbox[statemt[10] >> 4][statemt[10] & 0xf];
  statemt[10] = Sbox[statemt[22] >> 4][statemt[22] & 0xf];
  statemt[22] = temp;

  temp = Sbox[statemt[3] >> 4][statemt[3] & 0xf];
  statemt[3] = Sbox[statemt[19] >> 4][statemt[19] & 0xf];
  statemt[19] = temp;
  temp = Sbox[statemt[7] >> 4][statemt[7] & 0xf];
  statemt[7] = Sbox[statemt[23] >> 4][statemt[23] & 0xf];
  statemt[23] = temp;
  temp = Sbox[statemt[11] >> 4][statemt[11] & 0xf];
  statemt[11] = Sbox[statemt[27] >> 4][statemt[27] & 0xf];
  statemt[27] = temp;
  temp = Sbox[statemt[15] >> 4][statemt[15] & 0xf];
  statemt[15] = Sbox[statemt[31] >> 4][statemt[31] & 0xf];
  statemt[31] = temp;

  statemt[0] = Sbox[statemt[0] >> 4][statemt[0] & 0xf];
  statemt[4] = Sbox[statemt[4] >> 4][statemt[4] & 0xf];
  statemt[8] = Sbox[statemt[8] >> 4][statemt[8] & 0xf];
  statemt[12] = Sbox[statemt[12] >> 4][statemt[12] & 0xf];
  statemt[16] = Sbox[statemt[16] >> 4][statemt[16] & 0xf];
  statemt[20] = Sbox[statemt[20] >> 4][statemt[20] & 0xf];
  statemt[24] = Sbox[statemt[24] >> 4][statemt[24] & 0xf];
  statemt[28] = Sbox[statemt[28] >> 4][statemt[28] & 0xf];
  break;
}
} //end of ByteSub_ShiftRow

int main()
{
ByteSub_ShiftRow (statemt, nb);
return 0;
}
```

the output is always given as

```
temp is = 0x63
statemt[1] is = 0x63
statemt[2] is = 0x63
statemt[3] is = 0x63
statemt[4] is = 0x63
statemt[5] is = 0x63
statemt[6] is = 0x63
```

Comment: You are setting nb=4 in the 2nd line inside ByteSub_ShiftRow

Comment: ya, because i am choosing case 4

Comment: it is relevant. i am just making a simple statement saying that nb=4, for debugging purpose, instead of doing an if..else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`statemt` is a zero initialized file scope variable. In main you pass that to `ByteSub_ShiftRow`. So you wind up assigning `temp` with the value at `Sbox[0][0]` which is 0x63.

Likewise for the following assignments.

Maybe you meant to initialize `statemt` with something else?

Comment: Slightly more accurate: `statemt` is *uninitialized*. It *may* be initialized to 0 because of a debug build (which typically does that sort of things). In C terms, however, it is not initialized.

Comment: @Jongware: No - check the standard. It's guaranteed to be 0. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294772/does-gcc-automatically-initialize-static-variables-to-zero

Comment: @SteveFallows so it means that I have to initialise statemt to a certain value then I will get other results?

Comment: @Kiao - yes that would index to a different value in `Sbox`. However without really trying to understand the code, it's not clear to me what the values in `statemt` should be, or if they should be constant or computed according to some criteria.

Comment: @SteveFallows Thank you for your help. This is just part of the codes from the CHStone benchmark. I needed to transform the 2d array of Sbox to 1d array which i have already done so. Then, now I am taking a part of the codes to test if the transformed 1d array can be synthesized using the c-to-verilog tool.