# Why doesn't the compiler give an error when an uninitialized variable is returned?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int weirdVariable = weirdVariable  + 1;
int main() {
  cout<< weirdVariable ;
  return weirdVariable ;
}
```

I was just wondering how this un-initialized variable is not returning error and returning 1.So my question is, how/why is it returning the value "1". Is this program logically valid? Or is it some flaw?

Comment: Because global variables are *not* uninitialized.

Comment: I doubt this can compile successfully.

Comment: @herohuyongtao it does compile, that's the reason I'm posting it. Try compiling it here http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Comment: It does compile although return 1 is an error code thrown at runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not uninitialized. Variables with static storage duration (like a global variable) are first zero-initialized before any further initialization. So `weirdVariable` ends up with the value 1.

> *§3.6.2 [basic.start.init]* Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.

If you were to declare `wierdVariable` as local to `main`, it would be uninitialized. This will give you undefined behaviour because performing lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (read: using the value of) on an uninitialized object gives undefined behaviour.

> *§4.1 [conv.lval]* If the object to which the glvalue refers is [...] uninitialized, a program
>   that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior.

Comment: But sometimes I get errors from compilers saying that I haven't initialized certain variables, so those variables weren't static?

Comment: If they were local pointers, you need to initialize them for the compiler to know what to assign to them initially

Comment: @kotAPI Right, they weren't static.

Comment: @DavidKernin I'm using a GNU GCC 4.7.2 version. Maybe the results vary  in different compliers.

Comment: @kotAPI Undefined behaviour doesn't mean it's invalid C++. It's perfectly valid C++, but when you run your executable, anything could happen at all. A good compiler is able to warn you that you might be encountering this situation (as I think GCC, clang, and VS all do).

Comment: @Joseph Mansfield - Guess, UB is what Stroustrup meant saying -  "C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off".

Answer (score 4):

Static and global variables are initialized to 0 by default so it's perfectly normal

The C standard [ISO/IEC 9899:1999](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/standards) a.k.a. [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) (and C++) standards say this must be so. See item 10 in section 6.7.8 ("Initialization") of [WG14 N1256](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) for the exact text (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1294780/1938163)

By the way: **it is good practice to initialize static variables, also just to render the code more readable!**

```
static int myvar = 0;
```

Another drawback of not initializing them: **if a compiler doesn't follow the standard, you might get in trouble**

With regard to local variables that are both **NOT** static and **NOT** global, well, you might skip their initialization but that would yield undefined behavior. Don't really rely on it.

Comment: So you mean to say that I've declared weirdVariable as static by making it global? But the same happens when I've declared it in the main method..

Comment: I forgot to add that both static and global variables are initialized as so. Fixed

Comment: @kotAPI In that case, you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: I agree, and it's terribly compiler-dependent so you can't rely on it.

Comment: Using a GNU Gcc 4.7.2 compiler. Depends on the compiler perhaps, I get a lot of errors when I don't initialize variables and try to increment them. I think it's a good practice to initialize a variable than to let it be 0 and have a flawed program. Don't you think?

Comment: non-static variables need to be initialized otherwise you might get undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidKernin Yeah, especially in games. You don't want a character to spawn with 0 health rather than 100. :D

Comment: or -100.. just to say :)